# [iOS 8]Attempting to badge the application icon but haven't received permission from the user to badge the application

Tags: ios, notifications

I have a problem when I run my app on iOS. 
The log has an alert:

> Attempting to badge the application icon but haven't received permission from the user to badge the application

Although, I'm implementing in code run on function `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()`. This is my code:

```
    UIApplication* application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    //-- Set Notification
    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)])
    {
        // iOS 8 Notifications
        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
    else
    {
        // iOS < 8 Notifications
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
            (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }
```

Please drop me some advice to solve this problem. I really appreciate your help in resolving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn whether the user has given permission (in Settings) for you to notify through badges by calling `currentUserNotificationSettings`. If not, don't attempt to use badges.